# Unknown character at end of snippet titles in EmEditor 20.9

Tags: code-snippets, emeditor

After upgrading from EmEditor 20.8.1 to 20.9, the titles of some of the handmade and preinstalled snippets end with a symbol normally used to represent unknown characters (black diamond with white question mark).

Is this a bug?

If so, can this be automatically repaired or will I have to do it manually?

Comment: Could you post some screenshots?

Comment: This issue will be fixed on v20.9.1.